# Unable to render react component element

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, button

[image]I am working on the t-shirt store application . In which there are Admin controls the all the categories of products and the all of the products . I created ManageProducts component which handle the updating and delating the products by the admin . When I render it without any function it works properly and displaying all of the buttons . But when I add the mapping function in it, it does not displaying buttons and the products details . Also there is no any error in console..

When I console.log(typeof products) it shows an object.  there is nothing in that object
[image]

here is the code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth/helper";
import Base from "../core/Base";
import { deleteProduct, getProducts } from "./helper/adminapicall";

const ManageProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  const { user, token } = isAutheticated;

  const preload = () => {
    getProducts().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setProducts(data.products);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    preload();
  }, []);

  const deleteThisProduct = (productId) => {
    deleteProduct(productId, user._id, token).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        preload();
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Base title="Welcome admin" description="Manage products here">
      <h2 className="mb-4">All products:</h2>
      <Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/admin/dashboard`}>
        <span className="">Admin Home</span>
      </Link>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <h2 className="text-center text-white my-3">Total 3 products</h2>

          **{products && products.length > 0 ? (
            products &&
            products.map((product, index) => {
              console.log(product);**
              return (
                <div key={index} className="row text-center mb-2 ">
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <h3 className="text-white text-left">{product.name}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <Link
                      className="btn btn-success"
                      to={`/admin/product/update/${product._id}`}
                    >
                      <span className="">Update</span>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        deleteThisProduct(product._id);
                      }}
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <h1>No products found</h1>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Base>
  );
};

export default ManageProducts;
```

The part of code where I insert ** this is the code , when I write that buttons are not rendering

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I am not able to do it, instead  I inserted screenshot of it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx add your code and save it and share a link here. It will be easier check the code.

Comment: Here is the codeshare link https://codeshare.io/5eEzeK